# Elementor insert template from JSON

Tags: wordpress, elementor

So is there a way how to insert Elementor template inside the editor if I fetch templates JSON from external source with JS?

Its the same as I import templates from Elementor template directory, but in this case I have fetched JSON from server and need to import in current editor. Hope you understand. Thank you. :)